# mysql_query() returning boolean and causing mysql_fetch_assoc() to fail

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a small login class for an application of mine, however, I think my query is bad, because when I call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` on the **result** of the query, I get this error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

I'm familiar with how `mysql_fetch_assoc()` works, but I'm guessing the call to `mysql_query()` is returning false, which is obviously a boolean, producing the error.

Here's the query:

```
$loginsql = 'SELECT userid, username, password FROM users WHERE username=\'. $username .\' AND password=\'. $password .\'';
```

Note: I realize the "mysql_" function set in PHP is deprecated as of 5.5, but I'm using 5.3.8 and just practicing. I will refactor the application later using PDO.

**classes.php**

```
<?php

class connectToDb {
    function dbConnect($config) {   
        $connection = mysql_connect($config['host'], $config['dbuser'], $config['dbpass']);
        if ($connection) {
            mysql_select_db($config['db'], $connection);
        } else {
            echo "Could not connect to database!";
        }
    }
}

class registerAccount {
    function doRegister($regusername, $regpassword, $regemail) {
        $regsql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('$regusername', '$regpassword', '$regemail')";
        if (mysql_query($regsql)) {
            echo "Successfully registered!";
        } else {
            echo "Problem with registration!";
        }
    }
}

class loginAccount {
    function doLogin($username, $password) {
        mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        mysql_real_escape_string($password);

        hash('sha256', $password);

        $loginsql = 'SELECT userid, username, password FROM users WHERE username=\'. $username .\' AND password=\'. $password .\'';

        $result = mysql_query($loginsql) or die(mysql_error());

        $loginrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($loginrow) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $loginrow['username'];
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $loginrow['userid'];
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect username and/or password!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the quoting in the `$loginsql=...` line

Comment: Can I recommend using the `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_`? They have a set of non-OO functions that behave almost identically to the `mysql_` functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: @jcsanyi You can, although, I will be ditching the mysql and mysqli functions altogether when I refactor using PDO.

Comment: you know the answer? so why you don't add a check on mysql_query() if it is false that means no results, I would advice you to use prepared statements to protect your query from sql injection.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly That will come when I switch to PDO.

Comment: @dpl47 PDO is a way better, than the old mysql library, the sooner you use it the better, less code to be migrated later

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly You're exactly right.  The reason for starting out using the mysql functions is because I took a break from PHP and I'm getting back into it.  I can worry about details like what set of predefined functions I'm using when I actually go to do something with the application.

Comment: What does your `$config['db']` holds. Is it the right name of the database?

Comment: @FakeHeal Yes.  It contains the correct name of the database.

Comment: So if you run this: `$select = mysql_select_db($config['db'], $connection); if(!$select) die(mysql_error());` what does it show?

Comment: @FakeHeal Nothing changes.

Comment: Does it show the error?

Comment: @FakeHeal, yes.  Nothing changes.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11674313/250259) for how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mysql_query()` returns false if there's an error.  If it returns false, you can get the error message with `mysql_error()`, which should give you a hint about what's wrong with the query.

This is why you used to see a lot of these style queries:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT foo FROM bar') or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Calling mysql_error() produces "No database selected." However, I did select a database.  Let me edit in the code to the question.

Comment: Check the result of your `mysql_select_db()` call to make sure that it isn't failing.

Comment: Fixed it. It actually had nothing to do with the query.  I made a rookie mistake and didn't instantiate a new object of the connectToDb class on the login page before trying to call the doLogin method.